# how to convert the part of UIView into UIImage and display it in imageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimage

I have a view in which i am drawing the signature i want that the signature part of the view should be converted as `UIImage` and then display it in `UIImageView` here is the code which i got from net i am using for converting

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signatureView.bounds.size);
   [signatureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   logoImageView.image=img;
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope will help you.

```
 - (UIImage *) getUIImageWithmyView:(UImyView *)myView
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, myView.opaque, 0.0);
        [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage * myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return myImage;
    }
```

Comment: how to call this method and how will i assing this image to my imageView can you please help me out

Comment: call the function as call other in class like `UIImage *imageWithSig = [self getUIImageWithmyView: yourViewObject];`

Answer (score 1):

use my bellow method...

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

     //hide controls if needed
    CGRect rect = [signetureView bounds];//use your signature view's Rect means Frame;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

you can call this above method like bellow...

```
UIImage *tempImageSave=[self captureView];
```

Comment: how to call this method how will assign the image to imageView

Comment: you can call this method like this `UIImage *tempImageSave=[self captureView];` and assign it to `UIImageView` you can call this method when you want to capture image

Comment: can this be applied to drawing line so that we may only get the drawing line in image not the whole view.

Comment: @ParashJoshi please see thsi can these line drwan can be converted image not the whole view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538102/how-to-convert-lines-drawn-in-iphone-application-into-image

Comment: you can save it or display it temporory

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signatureView.bounds.size);
  [signatureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  logoImageView.image=img;
```

first endimagecontext and after that set/use that image in imageview